# OSGi Bundle with JAX-RS RESTful services couldn't start

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey, osgi

I'm writing bundled OSGi application for Glassfish AS. I have bundle with JAX-RS RESTful services, launching with Jersey (i used Vogella's turtorial). My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The problem appears when i try to autodeply bundles, exception:

```
SEVERE: WebModule[/spm]StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider: The class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider implementing provider interface com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider could not be instantiated: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider to com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider
    at com.sun.jersey.core.osgi.OsgiRegistry$OsgiServiceFinder$1.next(OsgiRegistry.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.AbstractRuntimeDelegate.<init>(AbstractRuntimeDelegate.java:76)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.provider.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.osgi.OsgiRegistry.hookUp(OsgiRegistry.java:391)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.osgi.OsgiRegistry.getInstance(OsgiRegistry.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getOsgiRegistryInstance(ReflectionHelper.java:737)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.getClassForName(AnnotationScannerListener.java:217)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationScannerListener.java:186)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:672)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:415)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:582)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:703)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1453)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1250)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.execute(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiContainer.deploy(OSGiContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.deploy(JavaEEExtender.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.access$200(JavaEEExtender.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:148)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider to com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3007)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.osgi.OsgiRegistry$OsgiServiceFinder$1.next(OsgiRegistry.java:147)
    ... 64 more
```

What can be problem is in? Tried to see sourse of these classes, and seems, that `LocaleProvider` implements `HeaderDelegateProvider`, and all is ok... very strange behaviour. Any ideas, what can i do in this situation?

Comment: Such errors usually indicate that the classes were loaded from different class-loaders. Is there any boot-delegation involved for these packages?